What is a word to describe someone that always questions if something is real. Like a moment captured saying it's photoshopped
Is there a word for someone that is constantly trying to make it irrelevant, or to down a person's photographs, saying they aren't real or they are photoshopped? You know how they do on social media. There is always someone making comments like this, then another person chimes in agreement with that person. Then the post seems to be a bully's fighting.  When all along who even cares it's a beautiful scene.

This question seems a bit more specific than the dupes, but it could be even more specific. Is it "She's used a filter, she's not really that pretty" or "The Deep State photoshopped that to cover up Clinton's trail of murders" or something else?

Some terms come to mind: Skeptic. Cynic. Know-it-all. Jerk. Wet blanket. Debbie Downer. Curmudgeon. Crank.
There are many ways to describe the characteristics of someone who doubts or dismisses everything.
